# A shell script to run tabix command on multiple files

Tags: shell

I have 22 files stored in my directory. All the files are alredy bgzipped and have.gz. I would like to index each file using tabix and convert all the files into.tbi. I'm interested in a script that loops through all my files and do this process but does not merge all the files together. I'm running this analysis on linux command line.

Thanks for all your help

Comment: Are you just trying to run `tabix` on every input file? One by one?

Comment: Hi Etan-yes I'm trying to run tabix on each file but I figured if I have a loop that can run through all the 22 files and make them .tbi will be much easier.

Comment: What does "make them `.tbi`" mean? Is that not running `tabix` on them?

Comment: yes, I meant  running tabix on all of the 22 files. Best

Comment: This is the command I want to run on all the 22 files:

Comment: This is the command I want to run on all my 22 files:  tabix -pvcf -f input.vcf.gz

Comment: And have you tried writing a loop to do that?

Comment: No I have not yet tried a loop. I was hoping I can use a loop to do that

Comment: You can, you should try it. You are generally expected to try to work out your problem before asking for help with it on this site.

Comment: Thanks Etan- I'm new to programming but I tried my best and did some search on linux. All my files are numbered and have same extension. for example ABC_1_XYZ.vcf.gz, ABC_2_XYZ.vcf.gz, ABC_3_XYZ.vcf.gz, etc. I used this loop saying for f in ./*.vcf.gz; do tabix -pvcf -f .vcf.gz; done. when I try to excute this loop, I get a question saying was bgzip used to compress this file? .vcf.gz. I appreciate your help

Comment: And *was* bzip used to compress the file? Or gzip? Because those aren't the same? And it looks like (from the `.gz`) that gzip was used and `tabix` expects bzip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the job: `for f in ./*.vcf.gz; do tabix -p vcf -f $f;done`